# In Batch: Read only the filename from a variable with path and filename

Tags: batch-file, dos, filenames

I am currently looking for a way to take a variable in batch and only parse out the filename.

For example, I pass my batch file a -s parameter from another application which is subsequently set to my source variable. The source file variable typically contains something like: C:\Program Files\myapp\Instance.1\Data\filetomove.ext.

I assume to read from the end of the variable until the first "\" and set the result to a new variable filename but I have not been able to use the "for /f" commmand successfully.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Update: Only standard XP or Windows 2000/2003 available...(can't assume resource kits installed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If its coming in as an argument to the script, i.e. %1, %2, etc, you can extract just the filename and extension into a variable like this:

```
set FILENAME=%~nxN
```

where N is the index of the argument. For example, this script will echo just the filename of the first argument:

```
@echo off
set FILENAME=%~nx1
echo %FILENAME%
```

Comment: Thank you! I was re-reading the help and was over complicating the %~nxI instructions. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Yeah. Those instructions are really pretty sucky, if you're lucky enough to even find them.

Comment: +1 was about to ask this, SO has a great duplicate question detector :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this instruction seems broken if there is an "&" character inside the name. I just had the problem with a directory called "NGC&Wii". Obviously, one can change the name, but in some situations, you may not be allowed to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly improved version :

```
set FILENAME="%~nx1"
```

The extra parenthesis will ensure that special characters, such as '&', will not interfere during batch execution.