# Batch File: Split File Name and Folder

Tags: batch-file

I would like to parse the folder name and file name from passed argument. Example:

```
my.bat c:\windows\test.txt
```

I want those to be stored as follows:

```
FILE_NAME=test.txt
FILE_FOLDER=c:\windows\
```

How can I do this?

I found [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454670/in-batch-read-only-the-filename-from-a-variable-with-path-and-filename) but it only gets the filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read the help with `FOR /?` or [How to get folder path from file path with CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659672/463115)

```
set "FILE_NAME=%~nx1"
set "FILE_FOLDER=%~dp1"
```